# Slack App not sending messages to channel

Tags: python, bots, slack-api

I am using Python to send messages to a channel as a bot user. From the slack doc, looks like the way to achieve this is to create a slack app. I created a slack app following this doc https://api.slack.com/apps?new_app=1, I gave the authorization to send messages to channels, which in the end generated an oauth token , which I used in my script as follows

```
def slack_message(message, channel):
    print('sending slack message')
    token = '<generated token from app>'
    sc = SlackClient(token)
    print('Created Client')
    try:
        sc.api_call(
            "chat.postMessage",
            channel="<channel-name>",
            text="Hello, world! :boom:"
        )
        print('no errors')
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
```

There are no errors but I also dont get a push message on slack. How should I debug this?

Comment: That URL requires a login, we can't see the document you're referring to so you should find a public source. Also you're sure you're actually calling that function, right? When you step through it with a debugger everything seems good?

Comment: Not sure if there is any documentation without login , may be this https://slack.com/help/articles/215770388-Create-and-regenerate-API-tokens. But the point being it generated a token , but no way to validate if it works. Going to use the debugger , I added a try block to see if there are exceptions, but there are none

Comment: There are no errors in the debugger

Comment: would an [Incoming Webhook](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks) approach be useful in your case? Normally I've sent messages like this through the requests library.